# Two PHP arrays not being returned, two are

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

So here's the code:

```
function pullLists(){
  require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sql_connection/connect.php');
  $sql_sn = "SELECT sName FROM skills";
  $sql_st = "SELECT sType FROM skills";
  $sql_class = "SELECT class_name FROM class_info";
  $sql_race = "SELECT race_name FROM races";

  $r_sn = $link->query($sql_sn);
  $r_st = $link->query($sql_st);
  $classes = $link->query($sql_class);
  $races = $link->query($sql_race);

  $skillnames = array();
  $skilltypes = array();
  $classnames = array();
  $racenames = array();

  if ($r_sn->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $r_sn->fetch_assoc()){
      $skillnames[] = $row["sName"]; 
    } 
    echo $skillnames[1];
  } else {echo "No rows found for Skill Names.";}
  if ($r_st->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $r_st->fetch_assoc()){
      $skilltypes[] = $row["sType"];
    }
  } else {echo "No rows found for Skill Types.";}
  if ($classes->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $classes->fetch_assoc()){
      $classnames[] = $row["class_name"];
    }
  } else {echo "No rows found for Class Names.";}
  if ($races->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $races->fetch_assoc()){
      $racenames[] = $row["race_name"];
    }
  } else {echo "No rows found for Race Names.";}
  $resultArray = array($skillnames, $classnames, $racenames);
  echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
```

If I run it as-is, I get an error in my Chrome Console saying "**Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected end of input**" and points at my .js file that's calling this function (via AJAX and all that). However, if I remove `$skillnames` from `$resultArray`, it returns the other two arrays just fine and the .js script works great. I'm baffled. While I was debugging, I added the `echo $skillnames[1];` line just to see what would happen, and sure enough in my Chrome Console I saw the 2nd value of the `$skillnames` array. So as far as I can tell, it's pulling the values correctly, but by the time it gets down to actually `echo`'ing `$resultArray` it gets goobered up. What am I missing?

Same "unexpected end of input" error ends up happening when I throw `$skilltypes` into `$resultArray`. This *was* working for a while, but I ended up rebuilding the skills table in my SQL database. That's the latest change I remember that might cause this, but I don't see why it would. I'm convinced it's this PHP file, but if y'all would like to see the AJAX that's calling it, let me know.

.js for giggles:

```
//Pull Skill, Class, & Race Lists
window.onload = function() {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  userVar = "func=pullLists";
  xhr.open("POST", "pullSQLData.php", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4){
      responseArray = xhr.responseText;  
      targetDiv = document.getElementById('skillList');

      console.log(responseArray);

      targetInfo = JSON.parse(responseArray);
      // ... do stuff... 
      }
    }
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send(userVar);
}
```

`JSON.parse(responseArray);` is as far as it gets. `console.log(responseArray);` will either return nothing at all (not even a pair of empty square brackets) if `$skillnames` or `$skilltypes` are a part of the result from PHP, or will return the correct arrays if the aforementioned arrays are taken out of the result.

Comment: How does your JavaScript on the front end handle multiple return values? i.e. you're echoing an error message "No rows found..." as well as an array. You can't be doing that unless you've got some really smart JS code parsing out error messages and the data array. Comment out those other `echo()`s and see what happens.

Comment: Those "No rows found..." aren't getting echoed at the moment. It LOOKS like the PHP *is* pulling rows, so those errors aren't getting triggered. Those echoes won't be part of production. Just put 'em in there to try and figure this out. If they got triggered, they should just throw a DIFFERENT error, but will clearly say "No rows found for blah" mashed with the arrays. Make sense?

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Can I see your JS code just for giggles?

Comment: Sure. I've added it to the main post.

Comment: You can't output strings and JSON at the same time - do one or the other, or format your strings into JSON and put them together with your other JSON output.

Comment: Those echos don't trigger. They're superfluous at this point. Just didn't edit them out before I posted this. Aside from those, everything else should be outputting JSON.

Comment: Well, I'm baffled! Someone here smarter than me will have some suggestions.

Comment: I'm baffled as well. Things were working just fine until I rebuilt the skills table. I deleted it, and created a new table named "skills" and am using the same naming scheme ("sName" & "sType") in the table. Didn't think it'd be an issue. Haven't tried building a completely new table with a different naming scheme, though. I'll try that before putting my foot through this screen...

**EDIT** Nnnnnope. Still nothing. Baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. In rebuilding my "skills" table, I used parentheses in some of the names. After iterating through the array list on its own, I saw the Chrome Console throw some weird symbols when it hit those names.

Sure enough, renaming those values and removing the parentheses in the SQL table solved it.